# SEP 0024 Question: Where do the /info response fields referenced below come from?

Tags: java-sdk, payments, fees, anchor

I'm trying to develop an anchor server and going through the SEP0024 documentation. The documentation says "*Provide a full-featured implementation of /info*". Where does one find or create the fields in the response?

Are we supposed to have created some sort of datastore for these fields? When would these be created or set up?

My apologies in advance; the Stellar documentation can be quite confusing and it is hard to figure out how to do things described in the documentation!

`Request
GET TRANSFER_SERVER_SEP0024/info`

Response
The response should be a JSON object like:

{
  "deposit": {
    "USD": {
      "enabled": true,
      "authentication_required": true,
      "fee_fixed": 5,
      "fee_percent": 1,
      "min_amount": 0.1,
      "max_amount": 1000,
      "fields": {
        "email_address" : {
          "description": "your email address for transaction status updates",
          "optional": true
        },
        "amount" : {
          "description": "amount in USD that you plan to deposit"
        },
        "type" : {
          "description": "type of deposit to make",
          "choices": ["SEPA", "SWIFT", "cash"]
        }
      }
    },
    "ETH": {
      "enabled": true,
      "authentication_required": false,
      "fee_fixed": 0.002,
      "fee_percent": 0
    }
  },
  "withdraw": {
    "USD": {
      "enabled": true,
      "authentication_required": true,
      "fee_fixed": 5,
      "fee_percent": 0,
      "min_amount": 0.1,
      "max_amount": 1000,
      "types": {
        "bank_account": {
          "fields": {
              "dest": {"description": "your bank account number" },
              "dest_extra": { "description": "your routing number" },
              "bank_branch": { "description": "address of your bank branch" },
              "phone_number": { "description": "your phone number in case there's an issue" }
          }
        },
        "cash": {
          "fields": {
            "dest": { 
              "description": "your email address. Your cashout PIN will be sent here. If not provided, your account's default email will be used",
              "optional": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ETH": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  },
  "fee": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "transactions": {
    "enabled": true, 
    "authentication_required": true
  },
  "transaction": {
    "enabled": false,
    "authentication_required": true
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Those fields are for sep6 not sep24, where are you seeing this referenced for sep24? 
https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0024.md#info